# scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh with fixed seed

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, eigenvalue

I am trying to use [scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html) with fixed seed.

In order to that, I need to specify the v0 parameter. However, I am unable to figure out what exactly needs to go into v0, as the documentation is very meagre here (it merely says numpy.ndarray) and the error message is not informative for me.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse.linalg

A = scipy.sparse.rand(10,10)
# v0 = np.random.rand(10,10)
v0 = np.random.rand(10,5)
w, v = scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh(A, k=5, v0=v0)
```

Error:

> error: failed in converting 10th argument `workd' of _arpack.dsaupd to
>   C/Fortran array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to get reproducible results from `eigsh` is:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse.linalg

np.random.seed(0)
A = scipy.sparse.rand(10,10)
v0 = np.random.rand(min(A.shape))
w, v = scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh(A, k=5, v0=v0)
```

Same results everytime.
(Credit to @hpaulj for the correct comment)

Note that fixing the seed without setting `v0` is not sufficient:

```
np.random.seed(0)
A = scipy.sparse.rand(10,10)
w, v = scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh(A, k=5)
```

Different results every time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the documentation do not mention anywhere that parameter `v0` has to do anything with seed. It says

> v0 : ndarray, optional
>   Starting vector for iteration. Default: random

And from my naive understanding its the initial vector when it starts to find *eigenvalues* and *eigenvectors* it takes this parameter `v0` as initial vector to start from, now to the `seed` thing, we use `seed` to fix the numbers generated for these vectors. So your question really doesn't make sense. Even if you get this program running, you will have different results and to avoid that we use `seed` to make the results reproducible.

Again, I might be wrong here.

Secondly if you want to fix the seed for your method I suggest using `numpy` to fix the seed as `scipy` uses `numpy` to generate random numbers.

So the code will look something like this

```
import numpy as np 
np.random.seed(seed= 13)
```

and then if parameter `v0` is seed you can avoid it completely

```
w, v = scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh(A, k=5)
```

Again I could have posted this in comments but it is always better to put in some code to make your point clear.

P.S

I may have misunderstood your question, if that is the case please feel free to downvote.

Comment: As you quote - `starting vector`, not `array`.  `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh(A+A.T,k=5,v0=np.ones((10)))`.  The `svds` doc is more explicit: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.svds.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.svds